# LINQ within a foreach loop

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following (note how I am using LINQ within a foreach):

```
foreach (string recid in recids) 
{
     var recprec = (from rc in db.tblTrucks
                    where rc.ID == recid 
                    select rc                
                    }).FirstOrDefault();
}

if (recprec.TruckMake == "GM")...
```

I need to do some further processing based on `recprec` after the foreach but I get the following:

> recprec does not exist in the current context.

Not sure how to fix this. I tried to do something like `Object recprec = null;` but still no luck.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, the error is because you're declaring `recprec` **inside** the `foreach` loop. It loses scope once the loop exits.

You could move the additional processing inside the loop:

```
foreach (string recid in recids) 
{

    var recprec = (from rc in db.tblTrucks
                   where rc.ID == recid 
                   select rc).FirstOrDefault();

    if (recprec.TruckMake == "GM")
    {
    }
}
```

Just understand that it will be done once for every iteration. There isn't enough information in your question to determine if that's what you really want.

Answer (score 5):

Huh? I think you're confused. Every iteration through the loop gives a different instance assigned to `recprec`. Which instance do you want to process after the loop? Are you sure you want to be doing your logic after the loop? It looks like you can do it in the loop:

```
foreach (string recid in recids) {
    var recprec = (from rc in db.tblTrucks
                   where rc.ID == recid 
                   select rc                
                  }).FirstOrDefault();

    if (recprec.TruckMake == "GM")...
}
```

Or, maybe you want all the "things" that have `TruckMake` equal to `GM`? In that case, it's simple:

```
var gms = db.tblTrucks.Where(r => r.TruckMake == "GM");
foreach(var gm in gms) {
   // do something with gm
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`recprec` is being declared within the scope of the `foreach`. Once outside the loop, `recprec` is out of scope. Each iteration of the loop will give you a new instance of `recprec` (the previous instance will no longer be accessible). If you want to access it, access it inside the loop:

```
foreach (string recid in recids) 
{
    var recprec = (from rc in db.tblTrucks
                   where rc.ID == recid 
                   select rc                
                   }).FirstOrDefault();

    if (recprec.TruckMake == "GM")
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you declare a variable inside a loop (or other closed statement) in c#, it only exists within that context.  You need to declare recprec outside of your loop or put your if statement in the foreach loop depending on what you want to accomplish here.

So something like:

```
foreach (string recid in recids) 
    {

        var recprec = (from rc in db.tblTrucks
                       where rc.ID == recid 
                       select rc                
                       }).FirstOrDefault();


       if (recprec.TruckMake == "GM")
       {
           //Do something
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your if statement into the scope of the foreach loop.  Otherwise, even if this worked, you'd only be doing the conditional based on the last `recid` in the list.

Answer (score 0):

I avoid the for loops and for eaches and try to use pure linq. I believe the select many is what you are looking for...add more wheres as needed.

```
var results = recids.SelectMany( id => db.tblTrucks.Where( rc => rc.ID = id) 
                                                   .Where( rc => rc.TruckMake == "GM"));
```

This can be optimized a bit such as

```
var GMTrucks = db.tblTrucks.Where( rc => rc.TruckMake == "GM").AsEnumerable();

var results = recids.SelectMany( id => GMTrucks.Where( rc => rc.ID = id) );
```